# Defining request limits in Azure API Management with no subscription key

Tags: azure-api-management

I would like to impose request limits to some endpoints which are publicly accessible (no subscription key required) through Azure API Management. I am thinking of a rate limit of let say 100K req/min . How can I implement this?
I tried:

```html
<rate-limit-by-key calls="3" renewal-period="15" counter-key="@(context.Subscription.Id)" />
```

but then I got a lovely "Expression evaluation failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object." because no subscription key is passed..
I cannot limit by IP Address either..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to separate such anonymous calls into buckets, indeed use rate-limit-by-key, just find some other aspect of request to base key of.

If you want to treat all of them alike, just account in your key expression for null subscription:

```
<rate-limit-by-key key="@(context.Subscription?.Id ?? "none")" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

The policy also can be enabled by the API provider by introducing a custom header to allow the developer's client application to communicate the key to the API. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling#client-driven-throttling).

```html
<rate-limit-by-key calls="3" renewal-period="15" counter-key="@(request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Rate-Key",""))" />
```

Comment: I like the idea, but that would force us to change every single call in the client UI to pass this header. I was expecting no code changes. Thanks